# symbolic links fail when executed from systemd-nspawn

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, symbolic-link

I'm customizing an embedded system using `systemd-nspawn` to execute some commands into the environment. It works fine, but some symbolic links are not created.

This is the part of my script:

```
systemd-nspawn -q --bind /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static -D $MOUNTPATH /bin/bash << EOF

mkdir -p /home/pi/etc/network
cd /home/pi/etc/network
mv /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf .
mv /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf .
mv /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server .
mv /etc/network/interfaces .
mv /etc/default/hostapd .
mv /etc/resolv.conf .

ln -s /home/pi/etc/network/wpa_supplicant.conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ln -s /home/pi/etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces
ln -s /home/pi/etc/network/dhcpd.conf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
ln -s /home/pi/etc/network/isc-dhcp-server /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server
ln -s /home/pi/etc/network/hostapd.conf /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
ln -s /home/pi/etc/network/hostapd /etc/default/hostapd
ln -s /home/pi/etc/network/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
chown -R pi:pi /home/pi/

EOF
```

I get several error like this on both `move` and `ln` commands:

> Unsupported ioctl: cmd=0x40049409

The behavior is quite weird. The files that raised that error are actually copied and not moved. I guess the links are not created because the file exist (though this doesn't come up in the console, only the message above).

BUT, opening a shell in `systemd-nspawn` and manually launch those commands (copy and paste from the script above) works fine. All files are moved and links created.

What difference I should look for?